# Biber won't compile/cite this entry?

Tags: errors, texstudio, biber, compiling

I am not sure why, but everytime i tries to cite this entry, will my latex document not compile?

```
@misc{wiki::pinna,
    author = "Wikipedia",
    title = "{Auricle (anatomy)} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
    year = "2017",
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Auricle%20(anatomy)&oldid=759073366}},
    note = "[Online; accessed 12-February-2017]"
}
```

I am using Texstudio as editor. 
Os: Mac Sierra

```
$which latex
/Library/TeX/texbin/latex

$latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.21; using libpng 1.6.21
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

The error message i am getting is

```
line 108: File ended while scanning use of \field. \begin{document}
line 1: Undefined control sequence. \begin{abstract}
line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. ...e ear, also called pinna\cite{wiki::pinna}
line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. ...e ear, also called pinna\cite{wiki::pinna}
line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. ...e ear, also called pinna\cite{wiki::pinna}
line 202: Missing \endcsname inserted. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Missing \endcsname inserted. \printglossaries
line 202: Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition. \printglossaries
line 202: Use of \\blx@imc@printtext doesn't match its definition. \printglossaries
line 202: Argument of \@ssect has an extra }. \printglossaries
line 202: Paragraph ended before \@ssect was complete. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
line 202: Undefined control sequence. \printglossaries
: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
line 2: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 20: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 23: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 25: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 2: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 17: Citation 'human_freq_range' on page 4 undefined
line 5: Citation 'kaldi' on page 8 undefined
line 5: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 10: Citation 'keras' on page 8 undefined
line 10: Citation 'tensorflow' on page 8 undefined
line 10: Citation 'theano' on page 8 undefined
line 10: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 12: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 14: Citation 'scikit' on page 8 undefined
line 17: Citation 'Librosa' on page 8 undefined
```

My full .bib file looks like this

```
@online{human_freq_range,
    author = {Julian Heuser},
    title = {Sampling},
    url = {http://recognize-speech.com/preprocessing},
    urldate = {2016-12-26},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{kaldi,
    author = {Povey, Daniel and Ghoshal, Arnab and Boulianne, Gilles and Burget, Lukas and Glembek, Ondrej and Goel, Nagendra and Hannemann, Mirko and Motlicek, Petr and Qian, Yanmin and Schwarz, Petr and Silovsky, Jan and Stemmer, Georg and Vesely, Karel},
    keywords = {ASR, Automatic Speech Recognition, GMM, HTK, SGMM},
    month = dec,
    title = {The Kaldi Speech Recognition Toolkit},
    booktitle = {IEEE 2011 Workshop on Automatic Speech Recognition and Understanding},
    year = {2011},
    publisher = {IEEE Signal Processing Society},
    location = {Hilton Waikoloa Village, Big Island, Hawaii, US},
    note = {IEEE Catalog No.: CFP11SRW-USB},
}

@misc{Librosa,
    author       = {Brian McFee and
    Matt McVicar and
    Colin Raffel and
    Dawen Liang and
    Oriol Nieto and
    Eric Battenberg and
    Josh Moore and
    Dan Ellis and
    Ryuichi YAMAMOTO and
    Rachel Bittner and
    Douglas Repetto and
    Petr Viktorin and
    João Felipe Santos and
    Adrian Holovaty},
    title        = {librosa: 0.4.1},
    month        = oct,
    year         = 2015,
    doi          = {10.5281/zenodo.32193},
    url          = {https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.32193}
}

@misc{keras,
    title={Keras},
    author={Chollet, Fran\c{c}ois},
    year={2015},
    publisher={GitHub},
    howpublished={\url{https://github.com/fchollet/keras}},
}

@ARTICLE{theano,
    author = {Theano Development Team},
    title = "{Theano: A {Python} framework for fast computation of mathematical expressions}",
    journal = {arXiv e-prints},
    volume = {abs/1605.02688},
    primaryClass = "cs.SC",
    keywords = {Computer Science - Symbolic Computation, Computer Science - Learning, Computer Science - Mathematical Software},
    year = 2016,
    month = may,
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02688},
}

@misc{tensorflow,
    title={ {TensorFlow}: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Systems},
    url={http://tensorflow.org/},
    note={Software available from tensorflow.org},
    author={
    Martin~Abadi and
    Ashish~Agarwal and
    Paul~Barham and
    Eugene~Brevdo and
    Zhifeng~Chen and
    Craig~Citro and
    Greg~S.~Corrado and
    Andy~Davis and
    Jeffrey~Dean and
    Matthieu~Devin and
    Sanjay~Ghemawat and
    Ian~Goodfellow and
    Andrew~Harp and
    Geoffrey~Irving and
    Michael~Isard and
    Yangqing Jia and
    Rafal~Jozefowicz and
    Lukasz~Kaiser and
    Manjunath~Kudlur and
    Josh~Levenberg and
    Dan~Mane and
    Rajat~Monga and
    Sherry~Moore and
    Derek~Murray and
    Chris~Olah and
    Mike~Schuster and
    Jonathon~Shlens and
    Benoit~Steiner and
    Ilya~Sutskever and
    Kunal~Talwar and
    Paul~Tucker and
    Vincent~Vanhoucke and
    Vijay~Vasudevan and
    Fernanda~Viegas and
    Oriol~Vinyals and
    Pete~Warden and
    Martin~Wattenberg and
    Martin~Wicke and
    Yuan~Yu and
    Xiaoqiang~Zheng},
    year={2015},
}

@article{scikit,
    title={Scikit-learn: Machine Learning in {P}ython},
    author={Pedregosa, F. and Varoquaux, G. and Gramfort, A. and Michel, V.
    and Thirion, B. and Grisel, O. and Blondel, M. and Prettenhofer, P.
    and Weiss, R. and Dubourg, V. and Vanderplas, J. and Passos, A. and
    Cournapeau, D. and Brucher, M. and Perrot, M. and Duchesnay, E.},
    journal={Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    volume={12},
    pages={2825--2830},
    year={2011}
}

@misc{Hearing,
    author = "Wikipedia",
    title = "{Ear} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
    year = "2017",
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ear&oldid=761516891}},
    note = "[Online; accessed 12-February-2017]"
}

@misc{wiki::pinna,
    author = "Wikipedia",
    title = "{Auricle (anatomy)} --- {W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
    year = "2017",
    howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Auricle%20(anatomy)&oldid=759073366}},
    note = "[Online; accessed 12-February-2017]"
}
```

Comment: Looking at the printglossaries stuff, you have some other problems. Please provide a [minimal workinge example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/How_to_get_help)

Comment: Don't put url's in howpublished -- at least not when they contain dangerous chars like a percent sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\` before % and &, like this:

```
howpublished = {\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Auricle\%20(anatomy)\&oldid=759073366}},
```

Comment: Doesn't this keep the backslash before the `%` sign?

Comment: @Bernard. No it doesn't. It solves the problem. You are right url = {...} is a good/better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `url` field instead of `howpublished`: it will be read verbatim. I took the liberty to replace the access date in a `note` field with the access date in the `urldate` field, which is done for that. Also, I stole a code from @Heiko Oberdiek to prevent long urls from flowing into the margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@online{human_freq_range,
    author = {Julian Heuser},
    title = {Sampling},
    url = {http://recognize-speech.com/preprocessing},
    urldate = {2016-12-26},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{kaldi,
 author = {Povey, Daniel and Ghoshal, Arnab and Boulianne, Gilles and Burget, Lukas and Glembek, Ondrej and Goel, Nagendra and Hannemann, Mirko and Motlicek, Petr and Qian, Yanmin and Schwarz, Petr and Silovsky, Jan and Stemmer, Georg and Vesely, Karel},
 keywords = {ASR, Automatic Speech Recognition, GMM, HTK, SGMM},
 month = dec,
 title = {The Kaldi Speech Recognition Toolkit},
 booktitle = {IEEE 2011 Workshop on Automatic Speech Recognition and Understanding},
 year = {2011},
 publisher = {IEEE Signal Processing Society},
 location = {Hilton Waikoloa Village, Big Island, Hawaii, US},
 note = {IEEE Catalog No.: CFP11SRW-USB},
}

@misc{Librosa,
 author = {Brian McFee and
 Matt McVicar and
 Colin Raffel and
 Dawen Liang and
 Oriol Nieto and
 Eric Battenberg and
 Josh Moore and
 Dan Ellis and
 Ryuichi YAMAMOTO and
 Rachel Bittner and
 Douglas Repetto and
 Petr Viktorin and
 João Felipe Santos and
 Adrian Holovaty},
 title = {librosa: 0.4.1},
 month = oct,
 year = 2015,
 doi = {10.5281/zenodo.32193},
 url = {https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.32193}
}

@misc{keras,
 title={Keras},
 author={Chollet, François},
 year={2015},
 publisher={GitHub},
 url= {https://github.com/fchollet/keras},
}

@ARTICLE{theano,
 author = {Theano Development Team},
 title = "{Theano: A {Python} framework for fast computation of mathematical expressions}",
 journal = {arXiv e-prints},
 volume = {abs/1605.02688},
 primaryClass = "cs.SC",
 keywords = {Computer Science - Symbolic Computation, Computer Science - Learning, Computer Science - Mathematical Software},
 year = 2016,
 month = may,
 url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02688},
}

@misc{tensorflow,
 title={ {TensorFlow}: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Systems},
 url={http://tensorflow.org/},
 note={Software available from tensorflow.org},
 author={
 Martin~Abadi and
 Ashish~Agarwal and
 Paul~Barham and
 Eugene~Brevdo and
 Zhifeng~Chen and
 Craig~Citro and
 Greg~S.~Corrado and
 Andy~Davis and
 Jeffrey~Dean and
 Matthieu~Devin and
 Sanjay~Ghemawat and
 Ian~Goodfellow and
 Andrew~Harp and
 Geoffrey~Irving and
 Michael~Isard and
 Yangqing Jia and
 Rafal~Jozefowicz and
 Lukasz~Kaiser and
 Manjunath~Kudlur and
 Josh~Levenberg and
 Dan~Mane and
 Rajat~Monga and
 Sherry~Moore and
 Derek~Murray and
 Chris~Olah and
 Mike~Schuster and
 Jonathon~Shlens and
 Benoit~Steiner and
 Ilya~Sutskever and
 Kunal~Talwar and
 Paul~Tucker and
 Vincent~Vanhoucke and
 Vijay~Vasudevan and
 Fernanda~Viegas and
 Oriol~Vinyals and
 Pete~Warden and
 Martin~Wattenberg and
 Martin~Wicke and
 Yuan~Yu and
 Xiaoqiang~Zheng},
 year={2015},
}

@article{scikit,
 title={Scikit-learn: Machine Learning in Python},
 author={Pedregosa, F. and Varoquaux, G. and Gramfort, A. and Michel, V.
 and Thirion, B. and Grisel, O. and Blondel, M. and Prettenhofer, P.
 and Weiss, R. and Dubourg, V. and Vanderplas, J. and Passos, A. and
 Cournapeau, D. and Brucher, M. and Perrot, M. and Duchesnay, E.},
 journal={Journal of Machine Learning Research},
 volume={12},
 pages={2825--2830},
 year={2011}
}

@misc{Hearing,
 author = "Wikipedia",
 title = "Ear --- Wikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia",
 year = "2017",
 url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ear&oldid=761516891},
 urldate = {2017-02-12}
}

@online{wiki::pinna,
 author = "Wikipedia",
 title = "Auricle (anatomy) --- Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia",
 year = "2017",
 url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Auricle%20(anatomy)&oldid=759073366}
 ,
urldate = {2017-02-12},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


%%% --- The following two lines are what needs to be added --- %%%
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}


\begin{document}

Let's try this with \textcite{wiki::pinna}.
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]