# Use of \\blx@imc@printtext doesn't match its definition

Tags: biblatex

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 18, and now my LaTeX file (which has lots of biblatex/biber stuff) does this. What is the error?

```
! Use of \\blx@imc@printtext doesn't match its definition.
\text@command #1->\def \reserved@a {
                                    #1}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \let \check@...
l.692 ...rding to \textcite[288]{Kirby:traveller},
                                                   this hall is named from t...
```

Comment: That should not be happening. Off the top of my head I would not know of anything that would cause this particular error message and a Google search for that error only turns up https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353448/35864, which is not that helpful. I suggest you try to isolate the problem into a minimal example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) and post that here. Otherwise there is not a lot we can say.

Comment: BTW: I notice that you have received answers to many of your questions on this site, but that none of the answers are accepted. So while you are waiting for an answer here, please consider voting on answers and consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852). This shows which answers were useful and which helped you most. It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Ok - I never know what those up and down arrows meant!

Comment: The issue is isolated here: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/237#issuecomment-426969476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following a bug report about this issue (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/237) and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/768, the relevant macros were changed to be slightly more forgiving in the non-numeric input they accept. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/813. Completely arbitrary stuff in the `year` field could still break.

As discussed in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/237 the issue can be reproduced with a `.bib` entry similar to

```
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {\circa{1980}},
}
```

together with the `\circa` macro defined as

```
\newcommand{\circa}[1]{\textit{c}.#1}
```

The specific issue occurs because `\textit` in the definition of `\circa` is not expandable and the year field is expanded completely in an `\IfInteger` test (courtesy of `xstring`) when the option `datezeros` is set to `true` (the default and initial value).

The following MWE shows a quick work-around for the issue at hand and shows the preferred way to input circa dates together with a modification of the default to reproduce the desired output

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, datecirca=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\circa}[1]{\textit{c}.#1}

% disable datezeros and friends, but allow \circa to work in year fields (appleby)
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@imc@forcezerosy#1{#1}
\let\blx@imc@mkyearzeros\blx@imc@forcezerosy
\makeatother

% use EDTF (elk)
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{circa = {\mkbibemph{c}\adddot}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{datecircadelim}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {\circa{1980}},
}
@book{elk,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  date    = {1970~},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby *c*.1970; Appleby *c*.1980//References//Appleby, Humphrey (*c*.1980). On the Importance of the Civil Service.//— (*c*.1970). A Theory on Brontosauruses.]